# Convert CSV files from multiple directory into parquet in PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, parquet, data-partitioning

I have CSV files from multiple paths that are not parent directories in s3 bucket. All the tables have the same partition keys.

the directory of the s3:

```
table_name_1/partition_key_1 = <pk_1>/partition_key_2 = <pk_2>/file.csv
table_name_2/partition_key_1 = <pk_1>/partition_key_2 = <pk_2>/file.csv
...
```

I need to convert these csv files into parquet files and store them in another s3 bucket that has the same directory structure.

the directory of another s3:

```
table_name_1/partition_key_1 = <pk_1>/partition_key_2 = <pk_2>/file.parquet
table_name_2/partition_key_1 = <pk_1>/partition_key_2 = <pk_2>/file.parquet
...
```

I have a solution is iterating through the s3 bucket and find the CSV file and convert it to parquet and save to the another S3 path. I find this way is not efficient, because i have a loop and did the conversion one file by one file.

I want to utilize the spark library to improve the efficiency. 
Then, I tried:

```
spark.read.csv('s3n://bucket_name/table_name_1/').write.partitionBy('partition_key_1', 'partition_key_2').parquet('s3n://another_bucket/table_name_1')
```

This way works good for each table, but to optimize it more, I want to take the table_name as a parameter, something like:

```
TABLE_NAMES = [table_name_1, table_name_2, ...]
spark.read.csv('s3n://bucket_name/{*TABLE_NAMES}/').write.partitionBy('partition_key_1', 'partition_key_2').parquet('s3n://another_bucket/{*TABLE_NAMES}')
```

Thanks

Comment: so... last point {*TABLE_NAMES} is working for you ? I could not get what exactly you wanted.

Comment: looks like you just need to start the spark job for each table in a separate thread. Take a look at this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30214474/how-to-run-multiple-jobs-in-one-sparkcontext-from-separate-threads-in-pyspark

Comment: @Ram Ghadiyaram. Nup, the last point is not working for me. I want to do something like this, utilize *path to represent all of tables: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257111/reading-parquet-files-from-multiple-directories-in-pyspark

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mentioned [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37257111/reading-parquet-files-from-multiple-directories-in-pyspark) provides solutions for reading multiple files at once. The method `spark.read.csv(...)` accepts one or multiple paths as shown [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b9737c3c228f465d332e41f1ea0cece2a5f7667e/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrameReader.scala#L705). For reading the files you can apply the same logic. Although, when it comes to writing, Spark will merge all the given dataset/paths into one Dataframe. Therefore **it is not possible to generate from one single dataframe multiple dataframes** without applying a custom logic first. So to conclude, there is not such a method for extracting the initial dataframe directly into multiple directories i.e `df.write.csv(*TABLE_NAMES)`.

The good news is that Spark provides a dedicated function namely [input_file_name()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html?highlight=functions#pyspark.sql.functions.input_file_name) which returns the file path of the current record. You can use it in combination with TABLE_NAMES to filter on the table name.

Here it is one possible untested PySpark solution:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import input_file_name 

TABLE_NAMES = [table_name_1, table_name_2, ...]

source_path = "s3n://bucket_name/"
input_paths = [f"{source_path}/{t}" for t in TABLE_NAMES]

all_df = spark.read.csv(*input_paths) \
              .withColumn("file_name", input_file_name()) \
              .cache()

dest_path = "s3n://another_bucket/"

def write_table(table_name: string) -> None:
   all_df.where(all_df["file_name"].contains(table_name))
     .write
     .partitionBy('partition_key_1','partition_key_2')
     .parquet(f"{dest_path}/{table_name}")

for t in TABLE_NAMES:
   write_table(t)
```

*Explanation:*

- We generate and store the input paths into `input_paths`. This will create paths such as: `s3n://bucket_name/table1, s3n://bucket_name/table2 ... s3n://bucket_name/tableN`.
- Then we load all the paths into one dataframe in which we add a new column called `file_name`, this will hold the path of each row. Notice that we also use `cache` here, this is important since we have multiple `len(TABLE_NAMES)` actions in the following code. Using cache will prevent us from loading the datasource again and again.
- Next we create the `write_table` which is responsible for saving the data for the given table. The next step is to filter based on the table name using `all_df["file_name"].contains(table_name)`, this will return only the records that contain the value of the `table_name` in the `file_name` column. Finally we save the filtered data as you already did.
- In the last step we call `write_table` for every item of `TABLE_NAMES`.

**Related links**

[How to import multiple csv files in a single load?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37639956/how-to-import-multiple-csv-files-in-a-single-load/37640154)

[Get HDFS file path in PySpark for files in sequence file format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40136944/get-hdfs-file-path-in-pyspark-for-files-in-sequence-file-format)